# express validator: how to use OR

Tags: node.js, express

In a post request of my app, email is considered valid if it's either an empty string or a valid email string, how do I do this with express validator?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the express validator documentation.

```
req.check('email').optional().isEmail();
//if there is no error, email is either undefined or a valid mail.
```

Answer (score 0):

You... read the instructions for node-validator? =)

```
var check = require('validator').check;
...
app.post("...", function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    check(res.body.thatvar).isEmail();
    next();
  }
  catch (e) { next("TOTALLY NOT EMAIL! O_O"); }
}, ...);
```

Now go read https://github.com/chriso/node-validator